# Is it possible to change the background color of the screen of a Lenovo Thinkpad running Windows 10?

Tags: display

I have a severe eyestrain problem and would like to change the ongoing background color on my screen. Is this possible on a Lenovo Thinkpad running Windows 10?

I have dimmed my screen but for instance on my iPad I have a black background.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the desktop and choose "Personalize", when that window opens select Solid Color from the Background drop down box, then choose your color from the color picker.

[image]